# Azure CosmosDb create partition only

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

And probably I already know the answer, yet I would love some feedback.

I have a Azure CosmosDb without partition key (empty), I want to create one because the RUs are too high so the performance improves.

My would-be partition is Date (20181005).

My question is if I don't send the Date as part of the queries (most of the times we request the object by ID), will the partition help on the performance?

I believe that it will since physically will organize documents better, however, I would love some feedback.

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking but... you can't query without partition key, unless you specify a header enabling cross-partition query (which will query every single partition), and that might not be what you have in mind. But if you know the ID, you can do a direct document-read via the SDK and bypass the entire query engine.

Comment: @DavidMakogon The document id is only unique within it's own logical partition which means it's not enough. The resource id can do what you are saying but it's not something you can have without reading it from the document.

Comment: @NickChapsas you're right. My point was about query vs point-read, but correct - still need partition key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document id is only unique within it's own logical partiton. You can have multiple documents with the exact same id property as long as they are in different logical partitions.

If you partition your collection you have to deal with 2 (of many) realities.

- The logical partition size cannot exceed 10GB
- In order to have efficient queries and reads you have to provide the partition key value alongside your operations.

You can still do any querying operation using a cross partition query but this is something that should be avoided if possible. If you see yourself needing to use a cross partition query frequently then there is a problem with your partitioning strategy.

Bottomline is that your querying performance will be way worse without a partition key provided during the querying process.